# c# Bitwise Xor calculation that seems easy in R or nodeJS

Tags: javascript, c#, r, bit-manipulation

In R if I do `bitXor(2496638211, -1798328965)` I get 120 returned.

In nodeJS `2496638211 ^ -1798328965;` returns 120.

How do I do this in C#? (Think I'm struggling to understand c# type declaration and the way R & nodeJS presumably convert to 32 bits)

Answer (score 1):

In C# you would have to use `unchecked` and cast to int:

```
unchecked
{
    int result = (int)2496638211 ^ -1798328965;
    Console.WriteLine(result); // Prints 120
}
```

You could write a method to do this:

```
public static int XorAsInts(long a, long b)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (int)a ^ (int)b;
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
Console.WriteLine(XorAsInts(2496638211, -1798328965)); // Prints 120
```

Note that by casting to `int`, you are throwing away the top 32 bits of the `long`. This is what `bitXor()` is doing, but are you really sure this is the behaviour you want?

Answer (score 1):

`2496638211` is larger than an 32bit integer and in 64 bit systems with C# integers defaults long thus the hex value representation is`0x94CFAD03`. That `9` overlaps with the sign bits. This is also means that `-1798328965` results in `0xFFFFFFFF94CFAD7B` due to the negative number representation. So C# gets `0xFFFFFFFF00000078` that is the correct answer.

[JS XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) uses 32 bit operands so it truncates `2496638211`. Thus JS gets `0x00000078` that is not technically the correct answer. My assumption is that R does the same or similar.

In JS use `Number.isSafeInteger()` as well as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. In C# check `int.MaxValue` vs `long.MaxValue` to see the difference vs JS.

To recreate the JS behavior in C# wrap it in an `unchecked` block as per Matthew Watson post. The [unchecked keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) is used to suppress overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.